# Открыть с помощью

Tags: c#, wpf

VS2015, Win10, программа на C# WPF.

Если нажать на файл, который программа может "прочитать", и в контекстном меню выбрать пункт "Открыть с помощью...", файл начинает ассоциироваться с этой программой, но ничего не происходит (даже программа не запускается). Если же после ассоциации двойным щелчком открыть файл, то открывается через программу как надо.

Читал, что при "Открыть с помощью..." путь к программе ищется в реестре, я проверял в реестре он есть. Почему сразу по этой команде не получается открыть файл?

Можно ли как-то в отладке пройти этот сценарий?

**UPD:** Решил сделать вывод в текстовый файл аргумента, который передаётся программе. Файл создаётся, и в него записывается верный путь к открываемому файлу. Значит программа всё-таки запускается, только не до конца.

Comment: Что означает «ничего не происходит»? Что и с чем вы пытаетесь проассоциировать, и что вы ожидаете при этом?

Comment: Ожидание: откроется моя программа и указанный в ней файл.

Реальность: программа не открывается, буквально ничего не происходит.

Ассоциация файла с моей программой происходит правильно.

Comment: Попробуйте в начале пробега программы показать пустой `MessageBox`, пока он висит, приаттачиться отладчиком и посмотреть, где же падает.

Comment: Когда пытаюсь открыть файл через эту команду, программа приходит в конструктор MainWindow, а дальше в MainWindow_Loaded(обработчик Loaded) не идёт и остаётся висеть фоном в процессах.

Comment: А если запустить из-под Visual Studio с теми же аргументами командной строки?

Comment: Работает как надо

Comment: Попробуйте ещё `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (o, args) => { File.AppendAllText(имя-файла-тут, "\n\n" + args.ExceptionObject.ToString()); }`.

Comment: Ничего, никаких исключений

Comment: Странно. Тогда ищите по приложению, где оно выходит.

Comment: Попробуйте подписаться на «мирное» завершение приложения (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20347268/276994) и посмотрите stack trace.

Comment: Ну в крайнем случае по старой методике пишите логи по шагам кода в текстовый файл и смотрите, где падает, постепенно локализуя проблему. Рано или поздно найдете и место и некорректные значения.

Comment: Так я же говорю, что проблема где-то при загрузке MainWindow, конструктор отрабатывает, а загрузка окна не происходит, соответственно и обработчик Loaded не вызывается.

Answer (score 1):

Поставил в свойствах программы, всегда запускать от имени администратора и всё заработало.

**UPD:** Достаточно однажды запустить программу от админа, только запускать надо именно exe, к которому указан путь в реестре.

Comment: Эээ... Не самое лучшее решение. Вы случайно где-нибудь не пишете файлы в текущий каталог или каталог программы?

Comment: Файлы это архив, который, чтобы открыться в программе должен распаковаться во временную папку. И не обязательно ставить "Всегда от админа", достаточно однажды запустить программу от админа.

Comment: Кстати, выяснить это помогла именно подписка на необработанные исключения, как вы и подсказали. Просто я первый раз, наверно, напутал что-то.

Comment: Странно, а что давал однократный запуск от админа? о_О

Comment: В любом случае, рад, что помогло!